# How can I solve this layered network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

[image: This the p]

This is the similar problem, that I was trying to solve and understand the neural network concept.

```
My assumption:

At hidden layers node 1: 
1*1+2*1+3*(-5) = -12
At node 2:
1*3+2*(-4)+3*2 = 1

At output layer:
(-12) * 2 + (-12) * (-1) = -12
1 * 2 + 1 *(-1) = 1
```

Which resulted as a wrong output.

Comment: output layer will be -12*2 + -1*1 = -25. Just one computation not 2

Comment: Thanks, it's solved. @UG_

Comment: Added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output layer will be -12*2 + -1*1 = -25.

It will be just one computation not 2 as you have quoted in the question.